# JTA transaction across EventBus requests in Quarkus app

Tags: hibernate, quarkus, vert.x, jta

I am trying to implement a JTA transaction (in Quarkus app) across multiple EventBus.request calls. But, in my request handlers, I don't see the existing transaction.

How do I pass the request/transaction context through to my request handlers ?

Also, one of my request handlers uses Reactive Hibernate to persist data. Is there a way to get the hibernate calls participate in the JTA transaction ?

Comment: I dont think you can do that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68826779/xa-support-for-microservices